# Is there any Query to find the SP which contains errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dependencies

I am working in Sql Server 2008 and there is a change of table in my database. So I need to know which all the queries I am using that table or I need to know which all queries will throw errors.I has changed some SP to work fine.But there is a lot of queries which may cause errors.So If there is possible to find which all queries will return error like table not found or column not found.

I got the sp which is using by the following query

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%machine_ID%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

But the problem is that it will returns all the SP which is contains the name.But for some queries I changed the name but still uses 'machine_ID' as an alias name.So the above query will returns all the SP which contains 'machine_ID'.It may be used in query inside SP or it may be used as a parameter.So how can i get the query which will cause error due to absence of table or coloumn

In some sp it shows error like this while execution

```
Invalid object name 'tblMachineryHdr'.
```

Whether it is possible to know what all the SP will returns errors like this? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can figure this out with just a few queries - but there are tools available that can help you do this - especially useful to do this before you make a change!

See e.g. Red Gate's [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_Tracker/index.htm) as an option - extremely useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT [Name]

FROM    SYSCOMMENTS c 

    INNER JOIN 
        SYSOBJECTS o
    ON c.id = o.id

WHERE c.text LIKE '%mytable%'
```

Replace 'mytable' with the name of the table that you have changed. This will return a dataset with the names  of all stored procedures and UDFs that reference your table.

PS: Prior to changing the name you can run SP_DEPENDS 'mytable' to discover dependencies. But if the table name has already been changed then the query above should still work.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use `sp_refreshsqlmodule` to find missing columns in existing tables and `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` to find missing tables.

```
CREATE DATABASE test20101013
GO

USE test20101013
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo1
AS
SELECT willexist FROM dbo.bar

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo2
AS
SELECT wontexist FROM dbo.bar

GO
/*Returns foo1 and foo2 as table doesn't exist yet*/
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id IS NULL

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.bar
(
willexist INT
)
GO

/*Returns nothing as table now exists*/
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id IS NULL

GO

EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'dbo.foo1' /*Succeeds*/
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'dbo.foo2' /*Throws Error about missing column*/

GO

USE master
ALTER DATABASE test20101013 SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
DROP DATABASE test20101013
```